# .Net Core EF re including means

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hi i just start working on a project. I saw a context query line. It includes entity then includes again.
I don't understand whats what mean. I created 2 diffrent var object. when removed the self include line then debugging. I saw same thing.
This is the code

```
 using (var context = new DbContext())
            {
                var entity = context.Set<Book>()
                    ..
                    ...
                    .Include(x => x.Book)
                    .Include(x => x.BookAuthor).ThenInclude(x => x.Author)
                    ..
                    ... goes on
                return   entity.ToList()
                         
            }
```

I thought this is the same thing

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
                {
                    var entity = context.Set<Book>()
                        ..
                        ...
                       //remove .Include(x => x.Book)
                        .Include(x => x.BookAuthor).ThenInclude(x => x.Author)
                        ..
                        ... goes on
                    return   entity.ToList()
                             
                }
```

other example code is

```
 .Include(x => x.CategoryBranches).ThenInclude(x => x.Category)
 .Include(x => x.CategoryBranches).ThenInclude(x => x.Category).ThenInclude(x => x.BookCategories);
```

Can anyone explain the self include again. I saw it everywhere
Thank you

Comment: Can you post your entities at the end? Would be nice to at least have a [mcve] for the entities.

Comment: There s alot of entitys to cant post it.I can just post another example of the code

Comment: f12 on book and see what it is

Comment: The 2 names entitys are bridge tables i sure. It includes bridge to entity. Then includes bridge to entity to other bridge in second example. Can make it with just the second line. What mean to include again

Comment: `context.Set<Book>()` entity book has a navigation property Book... what this is i dont know, as there is not enough code to build the context. Pretty much what @Mafii said.

Comment: Yes it exactly calling with context.Set<Book>()

Comment: If you don't understand what `Include` means the obvious thing to do is: go to the docs.

Comment: I think i know means but the 3th example is differnet

Comment: There is no "self include" in the third example.

Answer (score 1):

If the Book has a Navigation Property called Book (that doesnt make sense with that name semantically, but technically it does), you have to include it to load it.

You can have a reference to yourself, just like to any other table via a foreign key, and have a navigation property for that.

Consider this example that makes more sense semantically:

```cs
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int ParentId { get; set; }

  public Person Parent { get; set; } // This is a self referencing navigation property
}
```

So now to use the parent you'd have to:

```cs
persons.Include(p => p.Parent). ... ;
```

to access the parent.

Comment: Is this mean  persons.Include(p => p.Parent).Where(p=>p.ParentId ==id) to get persons parent ?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading means related entities in a model class are loaded automatically.
The parent class provided by Mafii does not use lazy loading. That's why he had to use the `Include` method to load (or include) the parent entity (the related entity). If he didn't do it this way, any details under the `Parent` navigation will not be loaded. To load a related entity automatically, simply enable lazy loading by using the `virtual` keyword in the navigation property of the entity. This way, you don't have to use `Include` anymore.

```
public class Person 
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; } 
  public int ParentId { get; set; } 
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I think there is a performance downside to this. So, if you do this, you need to be sure you actually need those entities loaded.

Comment: I checked almost all entitys in proejct and they got virtual keyword to make relation other entity. I gaves lazy loading right ? but then why they include again and again.Virtual means all related data loads right ?

Comment: In EF core, just making a property `virtual` is not enough to make lazy loading work. And I wouldn't portray lazy loading as something that replaces `Include`. Unless you're a fan of the n + 1 query pattern.

Comment: @GertArnold okay, but it would work if I use a proxy to configure it in startup? Also, does it mean there's no point in the virtual if I still have to use include to access related entities (this is assuming I'm not doing any extra configuration for lazy loading)?

Comment: If you configure it right, yes. But what I'm trying to say is: `Include` is used to avoid lazy loading because in most cases that's a detrimental query pattern. And the question is about explaining `Include`, not offering an alternative.